# Remove attribute jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to remove all attributes in nested tags of `.text_default`:

```
  $("text_default").removeAttr("style");
```

But it is not working.

```
<tr class="layout_default">
    <td class="layout_default" align="left" valign="middle">
        <div class="text_default"> 
            <span style="color: rgb(64, 64, 64); font-family: Verdana, Arial; font-size: 11px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam orci ipsum, rutrum a sem sed, hendrerit euismod orci. Donec nec ornare mauris. Duis sit amet magna augue. Cras id nibh blandit, ultricies nisi a, feugiat nibh. Mauris eu tortor scelerisque, suscipit ipsum quis, fringilla leo. Duis ultrices, neque pharetra dictum iaculis, velit libero rutrum nisl, eu pharetra est nisi a risus. Etiam lobortis sapien turpis. </span>
            <br style="color: rgb(64, 64, 64); font-family: Verdana, Arial; font-size: 11px;" />
            <br style="color: rgb(64, 64, 64); font-family: Verdana, Arial; font-size: 11px;" /> 
            <span style="color: rgb(64, 64, 64); font-family: Verdana, Arial; font-size: 11px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam orci ipsum, rutrum a sem sed, hendrerit euismod orci. Donec nec ornare mauris. Duis sit amet magna augue. Cras id nibh blandit, ultricies nisi a, feugiat nibh. Mauris eu tortor scelerisque, suscipit ipsum quis, fringilla leo. Duis ultrices, neque pharetra dictum iaculis, velit libero rutrum nisl, eu pharetra est nisi a risus. Etiam lobortis sapien turpis. </span>
            <br style="color: rgb(64, 64, 64); font-family: Verdana, Arial; font-size: 11px;" />
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you forgot the `.` on the class name. As this is a typo that will not really be useful to future visitors, I'm [voting to close this as off-topic (#2)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you don't targeting your element correctly, if you'd like to targeting and id use '#' and if you'd like to targetting a class use '.'

```
//targeting id
$('#id-name') 

//targetting class
$('.class-name')
```

in this case you'd like to targetting all the elements inside div with the class text-default so you should use

```
$(.text_default *).removeAttr("style");
```

Answer (score 2):

your missing a dot for the selector and add the span who contain the style attribute :

```
$(".text_default>span").removeAttr("style");
```

Comment: Quoting panther: `.text_default has no style attribute` ;)

Comment: yes i miss this too i was editing my answer don't hit me :D

Answer (score 1):

`#text_default` doesn't exist and `.text_default` has no `style` attribute.

```
$('.text_default span').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: Hi Panther, I am trying to do this as it effectively a problem caused when users of our system paste into a rich text field - there are likely to be a whole bunch of variables so it will be hard to identify all possible styles which is why I was trying to get a one size fits all solution.

Comment: @gillers322: if you don't know exact elements, you can use eg. `$('.text_default *')` as a selector - it takes all what users put into.

Comment: Cheer Panther - I seem to have this working $('.text_default').children().removeAttr('style');

Comment: @gillers322: `.children()` are just direct children, `*` in selector takes all children, not just direct. But if you have just one nested level, it could be okay.

Comment: Hi Panther - yes that works too - another question, once I have cleared everything inside text_default am I able to replace the styling by referring to  style sheet or do I need add individual styles like $(".text_default").css("text-align","left");

Comment: @gillers322: you don't need to put there inline styles. Just style `.text_default` in your external stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the `style` attribute from *all* the children of `.text_default`--both the `<span>`'s and `<br>`'s--use `.children()`, like this:

```
$('.text_default').children().removeAttr('style');
```

[See it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/hna7vp7u/). This only handles the direct descendants of `.text_default`. To strip it off *all the elements* within `.text_default`, you can use the `*` selector, like so:

```
$('.text_default *').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: Thanks Ted - that clears the styling - now that's done how can I replace the styling?

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling a class you should use the dot:

```
HTML: <div class="class-name"></div>
JQuery: $('.class-name span').removeAttr("style");
```

If it's an ID you should call it through the sharp:

```
HTML: <div id="id-name"></div>
JQuery: $('#id-name span').removeAttr("style");
```